# jQuery Colorbox plugin destroy the container div after first view

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I have a simple structure (well in a complicated page but ok) i have a a div used tas container for some ajax answer showed when necessary using colorbox

```
<div style = "display: none;">
<div id="modal"></div>
</div>
```

And the folloving script (a part)

```
$.colorbox({
    onOpen: function() {
        $("#modal").html("Attendere prego...");
    $("#modal").fadeIn;
    },
    onClose: function() {
        $("#modal").html("Attendere prego...");
        $("#modal").fadeOut;
    },
    inline: true,
    href: "#modal",
    close: "Chiudi",
    transition: "fade",
    opacity: 0.6,
    width: "600px",
    height: "100px",
    maxWidth: "500px",
    maxHeight: "500px",
});
```

after this i have a ajax call and i put inside #modal the result (an html fragment).

If i load the page i click the modal open and show data or a message if empty, then i calose and if i click again nothing happens... i investigated the DOM uwith chrome's tools and found that after first usage the previus html became:

```
<div style="display: none;">
    <div style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

I used colorbox a lot and i don't remember other cases like this one, i cant' solve it any way i tried,

Comment: isn't `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()`? . You can also remove `<div style = "display: none;"> </div>` and have `<div id="modal" style="display:none"></div>` instead

Comment: No, There wasn't in other version of the code i did... these were last try i did i just tried to comment them and make transition none for colorbox... no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED! Was just the colorbox's version that was a bit old and the site now use latest jQuery, updating the colobox to latest release solved the problem completly

Answer (score 0):

You can have it this way:

in your HTML:

```
<div id="modal" style="display:none">
</div>
```

and your script:

```
$.colorbox({
    onOpen: function() {
        $("#modal").html("Attendere prego...");
    $("#modal").fadeIn(); // fadeIn function
    },
    onClose: function() {
        $("#modal").html("Attendere prego...");
        $("#modal").fadeOut(); //fadeOut function
    },
    inline: true,
    href: "#modal",
    close: "Chiudi",
    transition: "fade",
    opacity: 0.6,
    width: "600px",
    height: "100px",
    maxWidth: "500px",
    maxHeight: "500px",
});
```

Comment: No luck it strips out the idI i have to try to remove other scripts (that do other stuf and not apparentrly related to this one to see if someing else is wrong